# printing business cards - a kind of knapsack task

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I have some probably simple issue with a piece of code. This is a real world problem that arose last Friday and believe me this is not a CS Homework.

We want to print business cards and these can only be printed in blocks of 900 cards (100 sheets with 9 cards per sheet). The cards for anybody should not be distributed over several blocks. People ordered different amount of cards, E.G:

```
% "braucht" is german and means "needs"
braucht(anton,400).
braucht(berta,200).
braucht(claudia,400).
braucht(dorothee,100).
braucht(edgar,200).
braucht(frank,400).
braucht(georg,100).
```

I put together the following definition to find an appropriate block of 900 business cards:

```
block(0,[]).
block(N,[H|T]) :-
    braucht(H,Nh),
%   \+(member(H,T)),
    D is N - Nh,
    D >= 0,
    block(D,T).
```

This produces a nice list of blocks of people whose cards fit together on a 900 cards block. But it stops working if I activate the commented line "\+member...." and just gives me a "false". But I need to assure that nobody is getting more than once on that block. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that what you want to achieve is to set a constraint that `H` does not appear in the tail `T` of the list. However, `T` is still unbound when you call `member/2`, so that `member(H, T)` will succeed and hence `\+ member(H,T)` will fail.

If you don't want to use Constraint Programming, but use pure Prolog instead, you should use the check in the other direction and check whether `H` is already present in the list of people that has been aggregated up to that point. Something like:

```
block(0, List, List).
block(N, Rest, List) :-
  braucht(H, Nh),
  \+(memberchk(H, Rest)), % will fail when H is already in Rest
  D is N-Nh,
  D >= 0,
  block(D, [H|Rest], List).
```

The predicate `block/3` can be called from a predicate `block/2`:

```
block(N, List) :-
  block(N, [], List).
```

Comment: I see that my approach was rather naive and one has to take into account the way prolog processes definitions. But now I will be able to go ahead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: how does the constraint programming solution look like

Comment: There are several possibilities. Depending on the CP system, you may have a global knapsack or bin packing constraint available. You could also use a cumulative scheduling constraint to model a knapsack problem. If you only have "simple" constraints available, you could set one variable B with domain [0,1] for each of the possible elements of the list (this would naturally lead to each element being listed at most once). Sum up the products B*Value for all the elements, and restrict the sum to be at most the capacity. Then label the boolean variables.

Answer (score 2):

If the second argument in your block predicate is the "output", then your problem is that T is a free variable, so member(_,T) will always succeed. For instance:

```
?- member(anton,T).

T = [anton|_]
T = [_,anton|_]
T = [_,_,anton|_]
```

and so on...

Comment: I understand now. T is free because [H|T] is processed from left to right and Prolog does what it wants with T as long as I dont bind it. Thanks!